# Microsoft Sql Case stmt using stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am sending a list of int converted to string delimited by comma to the db. 
On the db, I need to check if this string parameter is null, if it's null I need to check for all the rows from the table. if not null I select the rows that matches the string parameter which is split into table using sql function split function. Below is my query. Any suggestions how this can be queried better?

```
MM.CheckID IN
     (select * from 
      dbo.fnSplitString((CASE WHEN @listCheckID IS NULL 
         THEN
         (STUFF(( SELECT v.CheckID FROM (SELECT CheckID FROM TABLE1) AS v
          ORDER BY v.CheckID
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ';') + ';') ELSE @listCheckID end), ';'))
```

Initially I had the query in Method 1, I received error 'select query returned multiple rows..' later I modified the query in Method 2 which gave me table of split values which I still think not a good solution.

Method 1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInfo]    
    @CheckID INT    
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        MM.CheckId,
        MM.Dept,
        MM.Name   
    FROM 
        Table1 MM
    WHERE 
        (MM.CheckId IN
            (CASE WHEN @CheckID IS NULL THEN (SELECT CheckID from Table1)
             ELSE (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@CheckID, ';')) END)             
        )
 END
```

Method 2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInfo]    
    @CheckID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        MM.CheckId,
        MM.Dept,
        MM.Name   
    FROM 
        Table1 MM
    WHERE 
        (MM.CheckId IN
            (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString( (CASE WHEN  @CheckID is NUll THEN
          (STUFF(( SELECT  ';' + cast(v.CheckID AS VARCHAR(50))
      FROM (SELECT CheckID FROM Table1) AS v
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ';') + ';')  
      ELSE @CheckID end), ';'))         
    )
 END
```

Comment: show the full query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are complicating too much, this is all you need

```
Where (MM.CheckID IN (SELECT CheckID FROM TABLE1) and @listCheckID is null)
   or MM.CheckID = @listCheckID
```

`(MM.CheckID IN (SELECT CheckID FROM TABLE1) and @listCheckID is null)` the condition works only when the `@listCheckID` variable is `NULL` due to the `AND` operator used in middle.

When `@listCheckID` variable is  `NOT NULL`, then this `or MM.CheckID = @listCheckID` condition will pull the value matched with the variable.

post the full query, you might get even better solution

**Update :** seems like this is all you need

```
SELECT MM.CheckId,
       MM.Dept,
       MM.NAME
FROM   Table1 MM
WHERE  MM.CheckId IN (SELECT * --select the column name
                      FROM   dbo.Fnsplitstring(@CheckID, ';'))
        OR @CheckID IS NULL -- to return all the records when @CheckID is NULL
```

Comment: Pரதீப் : Could you please explain the query, meanwhile I will post the full query. I send the string value of format  ('12;25') to database. I'm using the splitfunction to split the value to a table as they are integer datatype and check using IN operator. In your query I don't see a check of the parameter is null.

Comment: @BVidhya - I have added a explanation, not sure if that helps. Its basically `AND/OR` logic nothing much to explain. Also you are concatenating the values and splitting it back, instead you can use the subquery directly in `IN` clause

Comment: I have updated my post with all explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: -Thanks. I'll try your solution.

Comment: @Pரதீப்- what if I need to select from a table based on condition when 
                  checlid is null?

Comment: @BVidhya - when `@CheckID` is `NULL` then all the records will be resulted. This `OR @CheckID IS NULL` does that

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are doing in that snippet. Typically, you use the following approach:

```
where MM.CheckID in (select ? from dbo.fnSplitString(@listCheckID))
or @listCheckID is null
...;
```

The question mark is a placeholder - replace it with the name of the column from the table returned by the split function. And **don't** start lazy/bad programming practices by using the asterisk (*) to select every column - even if the table has only one column. Things change over time; make your code resilient.